# Best practice for organizing many file paths for a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script which copy files from one location to another location. Currently, all file paths are defined as strings directly in the script. Unfortunately, all these file paths blow up my script. How can I organize all file paths in a better way, except directly in the script? Should I use a config file?

Comment: Can you please post a relevant portion of your script so that we can understand what you mean by _blow up your bash script_ ?

Comment: Blow up means, I declared an array with all file paths. We speak about 20 different file paths. It would be good to export all this file paths for better maintains.

Comment: You certainly *can* use an external file. That said, if you need to handle completely arbitrary paths, you'd want your external file to be NUL-delimited -- as newlines are valid inside filenames on standard Linux filesystems. That said, right now this sounds more like an opinion question than one about concrete technical fact.

Comment: (it's fairly common to handle both NUL delimiters -- GNU tools trigger this with a `-0` argument -- and newline delimiters, as the latter are what one typically gets with human-driven manual input).

Comment: @Charles thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure about your particular requirement here.

It all depends upon the size, complexity, importance, and longevity of your script.

If the script is complex (many lines of code with significant logic and has many dependencies), it is good to do these:

- Have an environment setup script - or config file - that creates standardized variables like, job_home, job_temp, job_log, job_log_archive etc., and has some naming convention for a hierarchy of directories with a common parent (job_home in this case). Using upper case for this could be a neat idea, though it is against POSIX standards as highlighted by Charles Duffy in his comment.
- Create a function that sets up these hierarchy of directories as needed.  Have a library of functions if that would make sense.
- Source the environment setup and the library scripts in the main script.
- Carefully avoid all hardcoding of paths - use the standard environment variables instead.

Comment: re: upper-case variables -- this is a place where common practice and explicit POSIX convention differ with each other, as the latter explicitly reserves variable names with at least one lower-case character for application use.

Answer (score 0):

A common convention is to accept a filename which can be read from to retrieve a list of other files to operate on as an optional argument.

If you aren't using stdin for any other purpose, it too is a reasonable stream to use for the purpose. For example:

```
printf '%s\0' /first/directory /second/directory >dirs
your-script < dirs
```

...or...

```
find /top/directory -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | your-script
```

...or...

```
# pass a results from "find" via a filename
your-script -d <(find /top/directory -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

---

The use of `printf '%s\0'` and `find -print0` above ensure that the list is NUL-delimited; this means that a maliciously-constructed directory name (ie. `mkdir -p $'/top/directory/\n/etc/passwd\n'`) can't inject extra arguments (in the above example, `/etc/passwd`).

Reading a NUL-delimited stream into an array looks like:

```
array=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' dirname; do
  array+=( "$dirname" )
done
```